# What are some ways to secure REST APIs?

Tags: java, ios, security, rest, oauth

I have a situation where iPhone client Signs In with Google/Facebook

```
                   step 1
iPhone Client   --------——> Google/Facebook
```

Once Authenticated, client needs to get data from my REST APIs

```
                   step 1
iPhone Client   --------——> Google/Facebook
      |
      | step 2
      |
      V
  GET /transactions
```

**Question**

1. Since server is not aware if client is authenticated(Ideally client is authenticated), what are some ways I can secure my REST APIs to have confidence that it is reasonably secured against malicious attacks?
2. Also, I do not want to maintain user/passwords on server

Comment: Implement [OAuth](http://oauth.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into OAuth2, which is created to authorise user and allow access to secured resources. Here are some useful links for the same:

RFC:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

One link that can lead you wherever you want to:

http://oauth.net/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a key for each client in the response and when the client access (provide key in the request) the server again, compare if the key is a valid key in your key pool.

Comment: Dont you think, Key can be compromised?

Comment: It is possible. But there is no way to ensure total safe.